# Facebook Page Plugin on Safari (iOS and MacOS) not working

Tags: facebook, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk, x-frame-options

I am trying to implement the Facebook Page Plugin and it works fine on all browsers except Safari for both iOS and MacOS

Here's the code I'm adding (straight from the docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v15.0&appId=123456789012345&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="Dbo7zqru"></script>
```

and

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myfacebookhandle" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="550" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false"></div>
```

All I get is spinning loading graphic and various console errors like

> Refused to display
> 'https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F'
> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Any ideas why Safari has an issue but no other browsers, and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks

### EDIT

Safari -> Preferences -> Privacy

Then unchecking "Hide IP Address from trackers" allows it to work on MacOS

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Comment: Rather than editing your question to include the answer, why not post an official answer to your own question and then mark it as the accepted answer?